# Sidebar not showing up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" id="nav-bar">
            <ul class="nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
                <li>apply</li>
                <li>about</li>
                <li>sponsor</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="pages">
                <div id="apply-page"></div>
                <div id="about-page"></div>
                <div id="sponsor-page"></div>                       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #nav-bar {
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: red;
    background: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}

#pages>div {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 85vw;
}

#apply-page {
    background-color: black;
}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

The sidebar doesn't have a red background, and it doesn't show up in the dev tools, and I don't see the text in the

. What is up with this?

Comment: post in this https://jsfiddle.net/ and i will help u fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use % instead of vh/vw.

Answer (score 0):

You have a css overwrite problem:

```
 background-color: red;
 background: fixed;
```

Leaving only **background** erases all the other values you've set to it, so the correct way is:

```
 background-color: red;
 background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything